# ¿Como hacer que si cumple la condicion , no imprima nada?JAVA

Tags: java, bucle-for

estoy haciendo un programa de imprimir numeros pares entre 0 y 100.
Pero que no imprima los numeros entre el 20 y 50.
El problema es que no se como poner que no me imprima los numeros que se encuentran en es rango.
Por el momento hice esto:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumerosPares{
    public static void  main (String [] args){

       Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

       int num=0;

       for(int i = 0 ; i<100; i++){

           num++;

           if(num>=0 && num<=100){

               if(num%2==0){
                   System.out.println(num);
               }
           }   

           if(!(num>=20 && num<=50)){              
               System.out.println(num);
           }
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utiliza la instrucción `continue`. `Continue` hace que la iteración actual finalice y empiece la siguiente. La evaluación si el número está entre 20 y 50 se hace antes de evaluar si es par.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<100; i++){

           num++;

           if(num>=20 && num<=50){              
               continue;
           }
           if(num>=0 && num<=100){

               if(num%2==0){
                   System.out.println(num);
               }
           }   


       }
```

También se puede refactorizar el código para dejarlo más limpio:

Se cambia la condición de finalización del `for` para sea `<= 100` y de esa forma usar `i` en lugar de la variable `num`. Y como el `for` itera entre 0 y 100 ya no es necesario evaluar si `num>=0 && num<=100`

```
         for(int i = 0 ; i<=100; i++){

           if(i>=20 && i<=50){              
               continue;
           }
           if(i%2==0){
               System.out.println(num);
           } 


       }
```

Comment: Gracias :D ahora si funciona , me habia olvidado del continue jajaja , Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes poner la condición `if(!(num>=20 && num<=50))` dentro de la condicion: `if(num%2==0)` e imprimir el numero dentro de la condición `if(!(num>=20 && num<=50))`.

Asimismo puedes inicializar el `for` en 1 para luego asignarle el valor de `i` a `num` de esta forma puedes omitir el primer `if`.

```
for(int i = 1 ; i<=100; i++){
    num = i;
     if(num%2==0){
         if(!(num>=20 && num<=50)){
             System.out.println(num);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: @Diego Gallo, considero que tu edición es un intento de respuesta, deberías dejarle un comentario al usuario indicándole que le hace falta para mejorar su aporte y que sea **el** quien realice los cambios si los considera oportunos.

Comment: @Aprendiz, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

puedes aumentar esta conficion en un if

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<=100; i++){
       if(i == 20){
           i=50; //aca saltas al iterador 50
           continue; //le dices al for que continue con el siguiente número
       }

       if(i%2==0)
               System.out.println(num);


}
```

Con lo cual optimizas tu código y evitas procesar ese intervalo de números